# The region assignment problem

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am using Povray to render images over a cluster. Each worker node is going to render a partial image. The subject of this question is to find a suitable splitting algorithm.

Povray render pixel by pixel. But each pixel has a unique complexity and so it takes a different amount of time to render it.

I divided the image in many regions. For example, 2x2 pixels regions. And rendered some of these regions. The complexity of those regions affects the complexity of the surrounding regions and so the whole array of regions is filled with a complexity value.

I divide an image in regions. Each region defines:

- Starting column, ending column.
- Starting row, ending row.
- Complexity of that zone.

The objective is to create a list of Jobs that when merged covers all the regions. The jobs should have similar complexities.

Each Job defines:

- Starting column, ending column.
- Starting row, ending row.

Contrains:

- A valid macro-region for a job is in the form of a rectangle or square.
- The number of Jobs is N.

Comment: are complexities simply additive or related to area of region?

Comment: How many jobs should there be?

Comment: Could you make the objective a bit more precise? Perhaps you want a min-max criterion: among all jobs, minimize the execution time of the slowest job. Perhaps you also constrain the total number of jobs?

Comment: As the problem is currently stated there is one trivial solution: all regions in one job. We need more info about the number of jobs.

Comment: The number of Jobs depends on the number of Worker Machines in a cluster. So, we can say it is N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question.

As an alternative strategy, you could have a master-slave arrangement in which workers ask for a job from a boss process, do the work, and then ask for more work.  The boss hands out small fragments of work until no work remains.  The advantage of this strategy is that provided the jobs are chosen small enough (e.g. 2x2 pixel squares) all workers will be kept busy until very near the end, and you avoid the need to calculate explicit estimates of region complexity beforehand.

Comment: That is a very good option. Nonetheless the minimum time that Povray takes to in order to render a scene is 1.2 seconds(loading time). You start to see a difference in time when you render 8-10 pixels together. So it could be just a matter of adjusting to take the right amount of pixels, but such a number could be quite different between images. For example, images with radiosity and the same size could take 4x longer.

Comment: @Nerian: Bear in mind that it doesn't matter if some jobs take 4x the time, so long as the maximum job time is fairly small: if the longest job ever sent off by the boss takes 10s, the longest any machine will be idle is 10s (this would occur if 2 or more machines finished their current job at the same time and that job was the only remaining job).  Do you think you could estimate region complexity (in terms of processing time needed for a region) more accurately than that?

Comment: It takes around 20 seconds to reach a good complexity estimation so your thought is an accurate reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that I finally used is quite complex and inefficient, so I am open for next answers.

https://gist.github.com/gists/729677